# Wordpress taxonomies echo output

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, echo, taxonomy

I am building a site that will feature sellers, kind of like a deal of the day site, on the product page there will be something that will say this:

"Sold by: (Output Custom Taxonomy for company here)" Every product will have a different brand or company name, but I am just trying to output that taxonomy. Currently I am doing it with the "tags" in wordpress like this:

This works for tags: ---->

```
<span class="soldBy">Sold By: <?php echo $product->get_tags(); ?> </span>
```

I then tried this: to get the taxonomy rather then the tags, and it isn't working.

```
<?php echo $taxonomy->name ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_get_post_terms()` for custom taxonomies -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

An example code:

```
// assuming your taxonomy is called "company"
$companies      = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'company' );
$companies_list = array();

if ( $companies ):
    foreach ( $companies as $company ):
        $companies_list[] = $company->name;
    endforeach; ?>

    <span class="soldBy">Sold By: <?php echo implode( ', ', $companies_list ); ?> </span>

    <?php
endif;
```

Note: I'm note sure what `$product` is in your context, so if you are using `get_posts()` you might want to change the `get_the_id()` in the code above to `$product->ID`

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with this

```html
<?php  
  // assuming your taxonomy is called "company"
  $Brands      = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'brand' );
  $Brands_list = array();
  
  if ( $Brands ):
  foreach ( $Brands as $Brands ):
  $Brands_list[] = $brand->name;
  endforeach; ?>

  <span class="soldBy">Sold By: <?php echo implode( ', ', $Brands_list ); ?> </span>

  <?php
  endif; 
  ?>
```

And it ouputs nothing. Within brands I have three terms or brands. Brand1, Brand2 and Brand3. Still not returning anything.

Comment: `foreach ( $Brands as $Brands ):` should be `foreach ( $Brands as $brand ):`